# goto HTML document location dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

My page adds # to the html programatically and have this in the  tag

```
function InsertTag(){
//Add <a name="spot"></a> to the middle of this document
}

window.addEventListener('load', InsertTag, false);
```

my question is how can I make the document then jump to #spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion: use id's instead. If you have:

```
<div id="something">
```

Then `page.html#something` will take you straight to that div. It doesn't have to be a `div`, it can be used on any element. If you can manipulate the DOM to add that anchor, I am pretty sure you'll be able to do this.

---

Now... To get there, you can use:

```
// this approach should work with anchors too
window.location.hash = 'something';

// or scroll silently to position
var node = document.getElementById('something');
window.scroll(0, node.offsetTop);
```

See it in action here: http://ablazex.com/demos/jump.html

There are subtle differences between the methods. Eg: The first one will cause the location on the address bar to be updated, the second one won't.

If you want it to look nicer you can use a jQuery plugin, like [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

`window.location = currentUrl+'#spot'`;

where currentUrl is a variable having the address of the current url

Comment: tried it before. it keeps refreshing the page since i added #spot programatically.

Comment: oh yes. didnt think of it. window.scroll is the best option then imo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var el = document.getElementById('spot');
var eloffsetTop = el.offsetTop;
window.scroll(0,eloffsetTop);
```